# $location.search empty when preceeded by hashed URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have query params I need to persist between routes. I have a resolve function that works using `$location.search()`, but when there's a hashed URL, `$location.search()` turns into an empty object. Is there any way to get my values out of `$location.search` when there's a preceding hash?

**URL is:**
http://localhost:8080/faq#business?gmbsrc=yada&ppsrc=yada

`$location.hash()` returns `business?gmbsrc=yada&ppsrc=yada`

`$location.search()` returns `Object {}` rather than `{gmbsrc: "yada", ppsrc : "yada"}`

**Angular:** v1.2.15

**Chrome:** Latest.

**HTML5 Mode:** On

Comment: @Chris Updated question with info. :}

Comment: The URL is built wrong, the hash should come after the query parameters

Comment: Suvi's correct.  You'll need to parse `$location.hash()` if you're using that URL format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JS to parse out the params if you're using the "hash-first" URL format with a query string after it:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/get-query-params-object/

Comment: This pointed me in the correct direction! Used `$location.search(angular.extend($location.hash().substring($location.hash().indexOf('?') + 1)));` Thanks!